# Place All Resulting Rows from MySQL Query in Arrays

Tags: php, mysql

**I have the following MySQL query:**

```
$imgDimensions_query = "SELECT imgWidth, imgHeight FROM (
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth FROM primary_images WHERE imgId < 10
    UNION 
    SELECT imgHeight, imgWidth FROM secondary_images WHERE primaryId < 10) as imgDimensions";
$imgDimensions_data = mysql_query($imgDimensions_query) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
```

**I would like to place all the results in two separate arrays; One for `imgWidth`, and one for `imgHeight`.**

I tried to do this using a `while` loop, but I didn't know what to use inside the loop to create the arrays.

**I'm going to explain what I will be doing with this information in case you think of a better method than using arrays:** I will be first removing any results from `imgWidth` and `imgHeight` if they match an external set of values. Then I will find the maximum values of both `imgWidth` and `imgHeight` *after* said removal, and placing those two values in respective variables.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mysql_fetch_asoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($imgDimensions_data)) {
    $imgWidth[] = $row['imgWidth'];
    $imgHeight[] = $row['imgHeight'];
}
```

Comment: I actually tried that while I was waiting, and it creates an associative array, even though there's nothing to associate. So each result is associated with a number, like this: `Array
(
    [0] => 750
    [1] => 563
    [2] => 605
)`. Is there a way to make a non-associative array? Or will it even be a problem given what I aim to do with the array?

Comment: That's not an associative array, that's a normal array. An associative array has strings for it's keys.... ie: `Array(['key'] => 'value')` Well, what do you want your `imgWidth` array to look like then?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Maybe I'm confused. I guess I was thinking the array would have no keys, only values. Is that even possible, or am I going crazy (thee's alway the chance...)...

Comment: I just realized what I'm asking for is impossible, and that PHP will fill in key values if none are specified. Sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: Haha if it didn't have any keys, it wouldn't be an array.

Comment: I don't know why I was thinking that way... especially with a background in mathematics... wanna lend some advice on removing specific values from an array if present?

Comment: Sure, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, I explained somewhat at the end of my question, but here: I want to check both arrays against two respective values. If each array contains its specific value, then it is removed. Same for any duplicate values. Then I want to extract the maximum value from each array and place them in variables. Ideas?